# gettext, how to handle homonyms?

Tags: php, gettext

Using gettext

**Single value**

```
echo gettext( "Hello, world!\n" );
```

**Plurals**

```
printf(ngettext("%d comment", "%d comments", $n), $n);
```

**English homonym?**

```
echo gettext("Letter");// as in mail, for Russian outputs "письмо"
echo gettext("Letter");// as in character, for Russian outputs "буква"
```

Same with the english word "character", it can be the character of a person or a letter!
How is gettext supposed to identify the right translation for homonyms?

Comment: The answer seems to be *contexts.* http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/Contexts.html Not sure how they're used in a PHP context though

Comment: Related?: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php#89975

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you are looking for is contexts for `gettext` which solves ambiguities like your example. You can find information about in the [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/Contexts.html). Still the needed method `pgettext` is not implemented in PHP so you might use the helper method stated in a [user comment](http://www.php.net/manual/de/book.gettext.php#89975) in the php documentation.

```
if (!function_exists('pgettext')) {

  function pgettext($context, $msgid)
  {
     $contextString = "{$context}\004{$msgid}";
     $translation = dcgettext('messages', contextString,LC_MESSAGES);
     if ($translation == $contextString)  return $msgid;
     else  return $translation;
  }

}
```

In your case it would be

```
echo pgettext('mail', 'Letter');
echo pgettext('character', 'Letter');
```

Comment: It would be better to use `textdomain(NULL)` instead of `'messages'` so that this function would behave the same way as C macro equivalent.

Comment: Moreover it is worth noting that one needs to give  `--keyword=pgettext:1c,2` to `xgettext` to let it know about this function existence during fetching of translation strings.

Comment: I have trouble using this function, first of all: the call to `dcgettext` doesn't seems to be correct, I believe that it should be `dcgettext('messages', $contextString, 5)`. Then: the function isn't returning the translation, or maybe there's something wrong with my PO file. I [asked a question about this issue here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31994975/gettext-to-work-with-context-pgettext).

Answer (score 4):

While trying to use the GNU xgettext utility to extract the strings from the source code I ran into some trouble with the pgettext() idea above.

At first it looks like it's going to work. Using the --keyword argument I can run the xgettext utility to extract these context and message strings from the test script:

```
echo pgettext('Letter','mail');
echo pgettext('Letter','character');
```

and get a .pot file with the expected output:

```
...
msgctxt "mail"
msgid "Letter"
msgstr ""

msgctxt "character"
msgid "Letter"
msgstr ""
...
```

But the PHP *gettext() functions don't allow me to pass the context strings - so I can't get the translated text.

Being able to use the GNU utilities makes things easier for me, so the solution for me was to use something like this:

```
function _c( $txt ) { return gettext( $txt ); }

echo "<P>", _c( "mail:Letter" ), "\n";
echo "<P>", _c( "character:Letter" ), "\n";
```

Now I run the xgettext utility

```
xgettext ... --keyword="_c:1" ...
```

against my test script. This generates a .pot file with simple msgid's that can be accessed via the PHP gettext() function:

```
...
msgid "mail:Letter"
...
msgid "character:Letter"
...
```

Next I copy the .pot template to the various LC_MESSAGE folders as a .po file and edit the translated texts:

```
...
msgid "mail:Letter"
msgstr "Russian outputs for Mail: \"письмо\""

msgid "character:Letter"
msgstr "Russian outputs for Letter of the Alphabet: \"буква\""
...
```

And my test script works:

```
...
Russian outputs for Mail: "письмо"

Russian outputs for Letter of the Alphabet: "буква" 
...
```

The documentation for xgettext is here:
http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/xgettext-Invocation.html

*(I'm still having a problem with poedit and "plural" text but that's another subject.)*

Comment: Thank you for sharing your experience, this is definitely an interesting turn of events, I did not expect gettext to cause so much trouble in php

Answer (score 3):

For the ones using Poedit like me you need to following. First create the function. I'm using one named _x like the one WordPress use:

```
if (!function_exists('_x')) {

function _x($string, $context)
{
  $contextString = "{$context}\004{$string}";
  $translation = _($contextString);
  if ($translation == $contextString)  
     return $string;
  return $translation;
}
}
```

Then on poedit you need to enter the following on Sources Keywords tab:

```
_x:1,2c
_
```

So when you need to use context translation you use _x function. Eg:

```
<?php
echo    _x('Letter', 'alphabet');
echo    _x('Letter', 'email');
echo    _('Regular translation');
```

I took all the info from these links:

- [Gettext to work with context (pgettext)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31994975/gettext-to-work-with-context-pgettext)
- http://www.cssigniter.com/ignite/wordpress-poedit-translation-secrets/

Answer (score 1):

I have made a package to provide an easy solution to the lack of pgettext in PHP.

See [here](https://github.com/DataLinx/gettext-context).

You need to install the package with `composer require datalinx/gettext-context` and then you can use

```php
echo pgettext('Mail', 'Letter'); // Echoes: письмо
echo pgettext('Character', 'Letter'); // Echoes: буква
```

Plural and domain override functions (npgettext, dpgettext, dnpgettext) are also implemented.