# Gettext to work with context (pgettext)

Tags: php, internationalization, gettext

I'd like to use pgettext to specify the context of some strings to translate, I've found that you need to add it yourself in PHP, which is what I did [following this post's instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16263617/3272179). I've changed it a little bit to make it work (the `dcgettext` function call had some errors):

```
function pgettext($context, $msgid) {
  $contextString = "{$context}\004{$msgid}";
  $translation = dcgettext('messages', $contextString, 5);
  if ($translation == $contextString) return $msgid;
  else return $translation;
}
```

But this function doesn't seems to work, the text is not changing when I change the language.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found a solution that is working well for me:

```
function pgettext($context, $msgid) {
  $contextString = "{$context}\004{$msgid}"; 
  $translation = _($contextString); 

  if($translation == $contextString) return $msgid;
  else return $translation;
}
```

Comment: This solution no longer seems to be working in PHP 7.0.x. The contextualized string remains untranslated. Has anyone else run into this issue with >=PHP 7.0x ?

Comment: @RichardLaffers Works for me in PHP7.0